# X Approaches Infinity! What does that Mean ? lim t → ∞ [(t^1/2) + t2] / 4t − t2 What should be my Strategy at Solving these types of problems.

Tags: calculus

I have had a tutor. He cannot convince me how one should solve limit approaching infinity problems. What is the strategy? Do you follow the limit laws if "the number x is approaching" is not in the domain? Since the number is infinity, what does that mean? I need clarity. In the below equation I am lost after step 2? Where did they get (4) / (t-1) shouldn't it be (4-1) / (t) if we are dividing by t^2? [image]

Comment: The first term of the nominator and that of the denominator go to zero if t goes to the infinity. This is because the exponents are greater then one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}=0$$So the idea is to get terms in this form.

The expression you are given is:$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{t}+t^2}{4t-t^2}\tag{1}$$What we do here is divide the numerator and the denominator of this expression by $t^2$. If you look at just the numerator and divide it by $t^2$ you get:$$\frac{\sqrt{t}+t^2}{t^2}=\frac{\sqrt{t}}{t^2}+\frac{t^2}{t^2}=\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}+1\tag{2}$$Similarly, if you look at just the denominator and divide it by $t^2$ you get:$$\frac{4t-t^2}{t^2}=\frac{4t}{t^2}-\frac{t^2}{t^2}=\frac{4}{t}-1\tag{3}$$If we now substitute (2) and (3) into (1) we get:$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{t}+t^2}{4t-t^2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{t}+t^2}{t^2}}{\frac{4t-t^2}{t^2}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}+1}{\frac{4}{t}-1}$$Hopefully you understand the rest of the steps.

Comment: Excellent presentation. You have taught someone today.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments :)